# How can I use a CSS selector to match two classes being present?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have the following HTML:

```html
<div class="form">
<input disabled="disabled" data-ng-model="dataId" type="text" />
<div class="disabled input-type-text">123</div>
</div>
```

I am trying to match the class of disabled and input-type-text.  I tried the following but it does not work:

```css
.form .input-type-text.disabled ,
.form input.disabled,
.form input:disabled,
.form select.disabled,
.form select:disabled,
.form textarea.disabled {
  color: #000000;
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
  border: 1px solid #adcede;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Can someone give me some advice on how I can match with CSS selectors? Note that this does work for the `<input>` but not for the `<div>`

Comment: do you have a node with `class="form"` enclosing the `div` you have shown in the question ?

Comment: Is `.form` a class or just a `<form>`?

Comment: This is inside of a <DIV class="form">

Comment: @Melina Please add a JSFIDDLE with your HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The selector is correct:

```
.form .input-type-text.disabled {
    border: 1px solid #adcede;
    padding: 7px;
    margin: 7px 0 2px 0;
    line-height: 16px
}
```

The issue is that you don't close `"` in `style` attribute:

```
<div class="..." style="...ding: 7px; margin: 7px 0 2px 0; line-height: 16px></div>
<!--                                                        Here  ----------^ -->
```

Answer (score -1):

You're looking for this:

> .form .input-type-text.disabled

Comment: I updated my question to show an <input> which works but the <div> still does not work. I checked with a debugger and the <input> CSS is chosen but not for the <div>

Comment: @Melina I've created a JSFIDDLE with the code: http://jsfiddle.net/3h6HD/ It seems that it works.